# OWIN Authentication And Timeout

Tags: owin

I am using MVC 5 with OWIN Authentication.
Here are the code for my StartUp.cs.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(60000000000)
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


    }
```

The expiration time is set to 60000000000 nano seconds.

Now the requirement is when the cookie is expired, I need to redirect to Login screen.

How to do that?

Comment: Just for curiosity, the unit of TimeSpan is 100-nanosecond unit, so should be 60000000000 "100-nanoseconds" units. 1 nanosecond = 1/1000000 milliseconds. 100-nanoseconds = 1/10000 milliseconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help someone to debug...
The error is in web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  </modules>
<system.webServer>
```

here the name Forms authenticationModule is a typo. it should be

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
<system.webServer>
```

And voilla it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/) example is more better:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
    },
    SlidingExpiration = false,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
});
```

Paste code above in Startup.Auth.cs file from App_Start folder.